# Total occurrences of a single digit from a string of digits across a range of cells in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

We need to count how many occurrences of each number are in a cell over a range of cells in the same column and output a tally of the totals for each number. See the attached picture and the desired output in the column next to it. We tried other formulas found online in both excel and open office with no results.

[letter Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZwWC.png)

[Working Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjjNP.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried in detail and what your problem is.

Comment: "10" includes "1". Are you sure you don't want to count "0" (zeroes) instead?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. We tried this formula just now and it worked for numbers but not letters.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND('G';A1:A254))))

Comment: and yes sorry, 10 was a typo, should have been zero. =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND('1';A1:A254)))) works for 0-9 but letters don't count for some reaosn.

Comment: Using find will only count one occurrence in each string, e.g. in the number 121 only the first 1 will be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula in `D1`:

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A:A,"@"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A:A,"@"),C1,""))
```

and populate down.

(you will need 2016 or later for `TEXTJOIN`)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Single array formula (ctrl+shift+enter !) which will work for strings with a maximum length of [5] alphanumeric characters (but you can easily modify the formula by adding a few numbers in the hard-coded array constant `{1,2,3,4,5}`):
`{=SUM(N(MID($A$1:$A$500,{1,2,3,4,5},1)=TEXT(C3,"#")))}`

You can add some further trickery to let Excel define the array constant, so the formula will work for any length of the string of digits :
`{=SUM(N(MID($A$1:$A$500,
COLUMN(INDIRECT("A1:"&CHAR(65+MAX(LEN($A$1:$A$500)))&"1"))
,1)=TEXT(C3,"#")))}`

The part in the middle (`COLUMN()`) creates the `{1,2,3,4,5}` array. You might have seen other versions of this formula, without the `CHAR`, which I use to create a reference to e.g. cell `E1` (knowing that 65 is the code for "A").

.

**Option 2**

This array formula (ctrl+shift+enter !) works in all Excel versions, but is not very "elegant" as you have to repeat the key part of the formula as many times as the maximum digits you have in your cells (this example is for max 3 characters):
`{=SUM(
N(MID($A$1:$A$500;1;1)=TEXT(C3;"#"))+
N(MID($A$1:$A$500;2;1)=TEXT(C3;"#"))+
N(MID($A$1:$A$500;3;1)=TEXT(C3;"#"))  )}`

The character you are counting is in `C3`. This will work for numbers and letters. If you can have five alphanumeric characters, you have to add two more `N(...)` parts, and replace the second parameter of the `MID` function with 4 and 5 respectively.